# What exactly does the "NoPadding" parameter do in the Cipher class?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, padding, block-cipher

Java's `Cipher` class supports the transformations [listed there](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). Among them are several `NoPadding` variants:

- AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
- AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
- AES/GCM/NoPadding (128)
- DES/CBC/NoPadding (56)
- DES/ECB/NoPadding (56)
- DESede/CBC/NoPadding (168)
- DESede/ECB/NoPadding (168)

I assumed at first that "padding" here meant the method used to fill the last plaintext block, if the plaintext's size isn't a multiple of the cipher's block size.

But in that case, how can a block cipher mode like ECB or CBC be used with "no padding"? Suppose that we use `AES/ECB/NoPadding` to encrypt a 250-bit message. The first block of the plaintext is obviously the first 128 bits of the message. What are the last 6 bits of the second plaintext block?

Comment: See Maarten's excellent answer, but in short: `NoPadding` doesn't *necessarily* mean padding isn't needed, it means you've taken responsibility for proper padding.

Comment: Well, yes, that's one way of explaining it. But if possible, I'd try and not perform padding myself and leave it to the library. There are however use cases where padding yourself is the only realistic option - and in that case `NoPadding` is really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, you cannot feed `Cipher` - in any mode - a 250 bit message directly. The reason for that is that - like in most runtimes - the byte is the smallest amount of data that you can process. If you want to encode 250 bits you will have to think of an encoding of those bits in bytes (e.g. by indicating the bits in the final byte that you don't use, as performed for the value encoding of a DER encoded ASN.1 defined BIT STRING).

---

DER BIT STRING example for just 11 bits set to 1:

```
05 FF E0
```

here there are 5 unused bits in the final byte (which are set to value `0`). So the first byte is simply sacrificed to indicate this fact - it's not part of the value.

---

Second, even if the input *would be* a multiple of 8 bits, then you would still not be able to encrypt using `NoPadding` for ECB or CBC mode *unless* the input itself is already a multiple of the block size. If you specify `NoPadding` then indeed no bytes are added (not even `00` valued bytes) so you'll get an `IllegalBlockSizeException` **if** the plaintext size is not a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES and 8 bytes for DES & DES-EDE).

The plaintext size is the amount of input bytes provided to the `update` and `doFinal` methods together. The bytes for the blocks before the last one will be buffered where required - only the final count matters.

---

From the `Cipher#doFinal` documentation:

> **throws:**
>
> ...
>     `IllegalBlockSizeException` - if this cipher is a block cipher, no padding has been requested (only in encryption mode), and the total input length of the data processed by this cipher is not a multiple of block size; or if this encryption algorithm is unable to process the input data provided.
>     ...

Note that this is a this is a terrible description in my opinion: during decryption this exception will be thrown by `doFinal` *regardless* of the padding used (again, only for ECB and CBC modes) if the size is not a multiple of the block size. The unpadding only happens after decryption by the block cipher and mode of operation after all.

Of course, the output of ECB & CBC mode during encryption should always be a multiple of the block size, so that would mean that the ciphertext was truncated or otherwise altered before decryption.

---

For GCM padding is not required (CTR mode encryption is used within), so `NoPadding` is the only realistic option, and any amount of data goes - but again the smallest element to be encrypted by `Cipher` is a byte. Even though the GCM *algorith* is specified in bits rather than bytes, this *implementation* doesn't support it.

Comment: Nobody really uses any of the 3 modes of CipherText Stealing (CTS) so I left it out of my description. The OpenJDK does not support CTS out of the box, but other crypto providers (like Bouncy Castle) can support it.

Comment: FYI, just tested: BouncyCastle RSA/ECB/NoPadding explicitly limits to 1 byte less than actual blocksize. So, for 2048 bit = 256 byte, maximum plaintext size is 255. Go figure.

Comment: @foo One bit less more likely. For RSA the value needs to be in the range [0, n) where n is the modulus. So if you AND the first byte with 0x7F then it will probably work. For RSA textbook encryption is insecure; normally you'd use hybrid encryption (wrapping or deriving a random secret key such as an AES key, and using that to encrypt the actual data).

Comment: That would make sense; the BouncyCastle source code however explicitly subtracts a full byte. See org.bouncycastle.crypt.engines.RSACoreEngine.java Line 49 ff.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I guess they take the simple route for moduli sizes that are not a multiple of 8.

Comment: I just found out that, in contrast to BouncyCastle, the SunJCE gives you a Cipher instance using the full block size for RSA, not deducting 1 byte - when you ask the SecurityProvider for the same "RSA/ECB/NoPadding". Is one of the two wrong, or is it simply a hidden "caveat"?

Comment: Well, what's wrong is to use RSA without any specific padding mode; textbook RSA is not considered secure. The only problem with the Bouncy Castle implementation would be to implement RSA-KEM efficiently on top of it (as that expects a shared secret within [0, N) where N is the modulus). So both methods are valid I suppose, as neither is a full mode yet.

Comment: (Using them for implementation of/with a specific padding mode is exactly where their difference causes problems.)